# как правильно распарсить строку в java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `add J. Martin "A Song of Ice and Fire"` и мне нужно разбить ее на три части. Первая - это `add`, вторая `автор` и третья `название книги`.

Подскажите как лучше.

Нашел способ такой:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
String[] values = pattern.split(value)
```

но каждый раз после этого собирать по кусочкам как-то не ок, какие есть еще способы?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать группы для этого. Группы задаются в скобках, нумерация с 1. Нулевая группа возвращает строку целиком.

```
    String value = "add J. Martin \"A Song of Ice and Fire\"";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s+(.+)\\s+\"(.+)\"");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String command = matcher.group(1);
        String author = matcher.group(2);
        String book = matcher.group(3);
    }
```

Comment: если не сложна объясни пожалуйста, почему после \\s+, точнее зачем? И оно ведь после "J. " второй пробел находит или оно идет до тех пор пока не наткнется на \" ??
спасибо

Comment: @Limpopo на случай, если будет несколько пробелов или символов табуляции.

Comment: Это нужно, чтобы пробелы не попали в значения в группах

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
String s = "add J. Martin \"A Song of Ice and Fire\"";

String command = s.split(" ")[0];
String author = s.split("\"")[0].replaceFirst(command, "").trim();
String bookName = s.split("\"")[1];
```

При условии что в первой части не будет пробелов, то есть вместо add не будет два слова например, и что внутри строки одни кавычки.

Comment: А если я ввожу с клавиатуры, то строка будет с кавычками? это можно увидеть только через дебаг? спасибо!